# How to move several elements under new parent, but only once?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to nest certain elements under new parent, but only for certain `id` values. Once they are nested, they must not repeat again.

Source:

```
<root name="root 1">
  <elem id="java" value="val1"/>
  <elem id="python" value="val2"/>
  <elem id="chair" value="val3"/>
</root>
```

Wanted result:

```
<root name="root 1">
  <container name="lang">
    <elem id="java" value="val1"/>
    <elem id="python" value="val2"/>
  </container>
  <elem id="chair" value="val3"/>
</root>
```

Additional catch: there's a possibility that not all targets for nesting will be available. Nevertheless, they should be nested with empty values.

Source:

```
<root name="root 1">
  <elem id="java" value="val1"/>
  <elem id="chair" value="val3"/>
</root>
```

Target:

```
<root name="root 1">
  <container name="lang">
    <elem id="java" value="val1"/>
    <elem id="python" value=""/>
  </container>
  <elem id="chair" value="val3"/>
</root>
```

My results keep repeating the `container`. How can I transform it as intended?

Comment: Can you post the template that *was repeating the `container`*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over lists of strings in XSLT 2.0.  So this might do the job:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:variable name="elems" select="elem"/>
      <container>
        <xsl:for-each select="('java', 'python')">
          <elem id="{.}" value="{string($elems[@id=current()]/@value)}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </container>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="elem[@id=('java', 'python')]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It does the job. Thanks :)